# JavaScript/jQuery - Convert Image to Base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I got following Code in jQuery:

```
$.get("img/background.jpg", function(img){
    // Convert img to base64
    var base64Img = $.base64.encode(img);
});
```

The Plugin I am using in the example is https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64 - which is not working at all.

Is there any way to get the Base64 (string) after getting an image in jQuery?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need to send ajax request to get an image. In javascript you can get image by simply creating new Image() object and setting the src property to the url of the image resource

Comment: There is already answer about this question here on stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: var base64Img = $.base64.encode(window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(img)));

Comment: **Error:** INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5 https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64/issues/1

Comment: <script>
                $.get( "img/background.jpg", function( img ) {
         var base64Img = $.base64.encode(window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(img))); 
       alert(base64Img);
       
      });
                          
            </script>

Comment: And ...

1. script must be run on the server
2. add file jquery.base64.js <script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>

Comment: solution: `var base64Img = $.base64.encode(window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(img)));`